# How to change the default icon with in the facebook login authentication screen in android

Tags: android

[image]

I want to change the default icon in the above picture with my app icon.

Comment: You need to go in the app which you have created in facebook and need to change the icons in the app itself.

Comment: Well, I tried that already but it isn't working that way. :-)

Comment: @aaramans Did you figure it out?

Comment: Maybe this is not a customizable icon.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/317451798411754/) the gear icon is not customizable:

> This is by design. The confirmation dialog does not serve the app
>   icon, but instead uses an non-app specific icon.